# How can I create more than one message in a Socket.io chat app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I'm building a dummy chat app to know how socket.io works (with react and node. Everything seems to work fine except that socket io emits more than one message.

It looks like for each character I type when then I press on submit it emits the message multiplying the total of characters per 2.

How can I solve this?

Thank you!

**Client**

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import { io } from "socket.io-client";

const App = () => {

  const socket = io("http://localhost:5000");
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setInput(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    socket.emit("chat-message", input);
  };

  socket.on("chat-message", (msg) => {
    console.log(msg);
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Chat</h1>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input onChange={handleChange} type="text" id="input" />
        <button type="submit">Send</button>
      </form>
      <div id="messages">

      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```

**Server**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);

const io = require('socket.io')(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: '*',
    }
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.on('chat-message', (msg) => {
        io.emit('chat-message', msg);
    })
});

server.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log('listening on: 5000');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are getting message twice from client and the server. It goes like this

1. you send(emit) message from client onto "chat-message"
2. then your client responds to socket.on("chat-message") and prints it once
3. your server responds to socket.on('chat-message') and emits it back to client
4. client react to re emitted message from server and prints again

Comment: Do you think you can show me how to correct this? Thank you!

Comment: Can you please add console log output to the question. Now when I am re-reading your question and seeing your comment on the other answer I am not sure that your question is understood correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Can you once try this code?

```
//client side changes
 const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    socket.emit("chat-message", input);
  };

  socket.on("receive-message", (msg) => {
    console.log(msg);
  });
```

```
//server side changes
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.on('chat-message', (msg) => {
        io.emit('receive-message', msg);
    })
});
```

Comment: Still have the same issue